# Can i run multiple command with artisan serve laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-serve

Is it possible to run some other arrtisan command when we run `php artisan serve` . at the same time ? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: run it in a different terminal/command prompt window

Comment: actually i want to create a queue job for send sms . But to run queue job i have to run "php artisan queue:work" . how do i run it into a server when server starts into  a  hosting ?

Comment: In [the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker) Laravel suggests to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to keep the queue worker running in the background

Comment: Did you have any luck with getting this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple commands separated by a semi-colon.

For example:

```
php artisan view:clear; php artisan route:clear; php artisan cache:clear; php artisan config:clear
```

Would that help?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup supervisor on the server. It will start the queue:work for you. It can also run multiple executions of same commands.

Comment: Thank you for that .